# Strip <style> blocks from HTML using regex

Tags: php, html, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

I want to be able to strip inline  css {}  blocks from HTML using preg_replace. Anyone know the regex for that?

**UPDATE**

i wont be controlling the pages. I want to strip all markup from a page, an just leave the content.

Comment: What are you running the regex on? If you are planning to do it on pages that you do not control, I'd be wary. RegEx cannot correctly capture the complexity of HTML.

Comment: I wont be controlling the pages. Is there anything else I could use. I want to strip all markup from a page, an just leave the content.

Comment: Not a duplicate. I want to find out how to strip style blocks. Thats the tags and the css inbetween.

Answer (score 5):

There is a great [3rd-party library](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net) that makes simple DOM manipulations like these really easy.

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($inputString);

foreach($html->find('style') as $style)
    $style->outertext = '';

$outputString = $html->save();
```

If you cannot use 3rd-party libraries for some reason, using [PHP's built-in DOM module](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) is still a better option than regex.

If you want to keep the tags but only remove their contents for some reason use `innertext` instead of `outertext`.

Answer (score 0):

For stripping inline css, this method seems rather odd to me. Why don't you approach this using javascript or even jQuery?

Just invoke removeAttr with jQuery.

[removerAttr | jQuewry API](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

Answer (score 0):

First, regexes are not the way to parse HTML.  If you actually want to parse HTML, and can't use an existing solution, then use the DOM module in PHP.  http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Fortunately, PHP already has a function that will strip tags from a block of HTML.  It is called `strip_tags()`.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: strip_tags will not remove a block of css. It will remove the surrounding tags but not the css inbetween.

Comment: That's not what you asked for.  You said you wanted to remove all tags.

Comment: i did? <style> css {} </style>

Comment: omfg. i clearly had css block up in my question, and someone edited it. WTF is happening to stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes, you said, and I quote: "I want to strip all markup from a page, an just leave the content."

Comment: It had "strip <style> blocks" and it was you that edited it!? haha.

Comment: No, you wrote, quote `"I want to strip all markup from a page, an just leave the content."`. *YOU* edited it. Here is the edit you made: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13707511/2